# Do I need to wait for stylesheet to load to use css selectors?

Tags: puppeteer, codeceptjs

**Intro:** In my project we use [CodeceptJS with Puppeteer](https://codecept.io/helpers/Puppeteer) driver, we also use the configuration [waitForNavigation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) set to `DOMContentLoaded` which does not wait for external resources to be loaded, including stylesheets and images, to start interacting with the page.

**Question:** Considering the stylesheets might not be loaded, would puppeteer be unable to find elements by CSS selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppeteer will find elements by CSS selector if element exist DOM.
It doesn't matter if CSS files are loaded or not.

But..

If you use `waitForSelector` with `visible: true` option, Puppeteer will be wait for element to be present in DOM and to be visible, i.e. to not have `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` CSS properties.

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the reply.